# Best way to implement multiple UITableViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am working on a project where users can upload the names of up to 10 songs. Everything works, I just need to display the “posts” when they are clicked. This will look similar to a post on other social network sites:

```
Username
Date of post
(Optional note - can be multiple lines, so no fixed height

Song 1
Song 2
Song 3
...

X likes

Username
Date of comment
Comment
```

So I basically have a UITableView to display the song and relevant information, such as the artist, album, song duration etc in separate cells. I also want to display the comments in a UITableView.

So, my question: should I add a UIScrollView and add all elements separately (e.g. the information on top as a regular UiView), because nesting UITableViews in a UIScrollView is not recommended? I have also thought about implementing the top and bottom views as a UITableViewHeader and UITableViewFooter, but then I am afraid for the dynamic height of both views.

Any suggestions on what might be the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: It took me a while to understand what interface you’re trying to create but I see now what the problem is.

Comment: @matt I might have needed to add some artwork to demonstrate, perhaps. But I am glad you understand the issue I am facing. Any suggestions on what the best approach might be?

Comment: I’d recommend a different interface. A variable height display above a table view is very unusual. I feel like you’re trying to crowd too much info onto one screen.

Comment: I’m not too concerned about it being too much information. The variable height will only depend on a UILabel which will contain the “note” the user submits. Thibk about it as “this is a nice playlist!” or “The music I really like”, so can wrap multiple lines. That’s the only vatiablr height there, and the comments on the bottom of course

Answer (score 0):

I've got a screen where I have two UITableViews side by side - it's a quantity picker (count and unit type).  Basically what I have is a "parent" view controller with 2 [container view controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1).  Inside each container there's a table view controller with the table inside. I can route all my table logic back up to the parent controller that way and keep all that in one place.  I've done it in a storyboard using autolayout to simplify things, but it could be done just as easily in code. Not sure if it's the 'best' way to do it, but it works great!

[image: storyboard screenshot]